# Access InputBox repeating user prompt

Tags: ms-access, export, inputbox

I have a large Access table. I have a query entitled qry_ExtractYear which I would like to have the criteria modified by the user and the the results exported. I have the code here which works but I am having the issue of being prompted repeatedly for sDate1 and sDate2 before the export occurs. What am I doing wrong please?

```
Sub ExportAnnualQuoteActivity()

Dim db As dao.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim qdf As dao.QueryDef
    Dim sDate1 As String
    Dim sDate2 As String
    
    sDate1 = InputBox(prompt:="Start Date YYYYMMDD")
    sDate2 = InputBox(prompt:="End Date YYYYMMDD")
        
    
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("Qry_ExtractYear")
    qdf.SQL = "Select * From [tbl_QuoteData] WHERE [Quote Date] BETWEEN sDate1 AND sDate2"
    
    DoCmd.Save acQuery, "Qry_ExtractYear"
    
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Qry_ExtractYear", acFormatXLSX, "T:\Actuary\Metrics\NB\Data\Yearly\tbl_QuoteData_" & Left(sDate2, 4) & ".xlsx", True
    
 
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Study my article on how to input a validated date value: [Entering ISO formatted date with input mask and full validation in Microsoft Access](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/24659/Entering-ISO-formatted-date-with-input-mask-and-full-validation-in-Microsoft-Access.html?preview=Eh7VEzgKeXU%3D).

Answer (score 0):

It's because the constructed SQL has literal text "sDate1 AND sDate2" and not the values of those variables. Concatenate variables and use date/time # delimiter.

```
WHERE [Quote Date] BETWEEN #" & sDate1 & "# AND #" & sDate2 & "#"
```

If field is text type, use apostrophe delimiter instead of #. Number fields do not require delimiters.

Advise not to use InputBox as cannot easily validate user input. Reference controls on form for variable user input.

Comment: The Quote Date field is not a date/time field in the data. It is a string YYYYMMDD

Comment: Then replace # with apostrophe. Why is a date saved to a text field?

Comment: That is just how the date is presented from the source file. All dates are by default YYYYMMDD and must be converted to date field using a Date() function if needed. I don't really need the date field to be a date field for my purposes.